# Filter a json with a variable inline not correct

Tags: karate

I create a script to filter a list user that not include the specified one. But when I tried:

```
    * def userId = response.data[0].id
    * def filter = ''
    * def users = get[0] response.data[?(@.id!="bd04b9f0-c254-4f23-9fed-6a0300692bbb")]
    * print users.id
```

is correct

But I want re-use a value form previous step like:

```
    * def userId = response.data[0].id
    * def filter = 'bd04b9f0-c254-4f23-9fed-6a0300692bbb'
    * def users = get[0] response.data[?(@.id!="#(filter)")]
    * print users.id
```

Is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#jsonpath-filters

```
* def users = karate.jsonPath(response, "$.data[?(@.id!='" + filter + "')]")[0]
```